# StackOverflow when filtering datoms

Tags: clojure, datomic

I'm trying to filter through a database, based on the keyword patter match.

To do this, I wrote ->

```
(defn find-users
  [db keyword]
  (if (>=  (count keyword) 3)
      (let [login-pattern (login-pattern keyword)]
        (->> (d/datoms db :aevt :user/name)
             (filter #(re-matches login-pattern (:v %)))
             (map #(d/entity db (:e %)))))
      []))
```

But, I'm getting a StackOverflow error.

I think it's because of `(map #(d/entity db (:e %)))`

When I plainly do `(map :e)`, the function works.

I'm a bit confused as to why the Stackoverflow would happen though, the queries I'm performing with map :v are returning only a few entities.

What's happening here?

Comment: Are there circular references in the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a little curious as to why not just use query? You can use predicate expression clauses for the same purpose that you've built the filter/map scenario above. See "Expression Clauses" at: http://docs.datomic.com/query.html

```
(defn find-users
  [db keyword]
  (if (>= (count keyword) 3)
    (map #(d/entity db (first %))
         (d/q '[:find ?e
                :in $ ?login-pattern
                :where
                [?e :user/name ?name]
                [(re-matches ?login-pattern ?name)]]
              db
              (login-pattern keyword)))
         []))
```

The query engine is likely to handle the size of intermediate results better than raw sequence manipulations.